# Why doesn't router.push({pathname: 'somewhere', query: {id: 1234}}) work on app router?

Tags: next.js, routes, next.js13, app-router

How to change route.query in nextjs app directory in documentation I found

```
'use client'
 
import { useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation'
 
export default function SearchBar() {
  const searchParams = useSearchParams()
 
  const search = searchParams.get('search')
 
  // URL -> `/dashboard?search=my-project`
  // `search` -> 'my-project'
  return <>Search: {search}</>
}
```

but there is no like searchParams.set. In pages directory that was easy

I had tried `searchParams.set('search')` but that was read-only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`useSearchParams` returns **READ ONLY** URL searchParams which means you can not set the query with this hook.

On the same page you've copied this code snippet you can find a section [Updating searchParams](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-search-params#updating-searchparams)

> You can use [useRouter](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-router) or [Link](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/components/link) to set new searchParams. After a navigation is performed, the current page.js will receive an updated searchParams prop.

```js
export default function ExampleClientComponent() {
  const router = useRouter()
  const pathname = usePathname()
  const searchParams = useSearchParams()!
 
  // Get a new searchParams string by merging the current
  // searchParams with a provided key/value pair
  const createQueryString = useCallback(
    (name: string, value: string) => {
      const params = new URLSearchParams(searchParams)
      params.set(name, value)
 
      return params.toString()
    },
    [searchParams]
  )
 
  return (
    <>
      <p>Sort By</p>
 
      {/* using useRouter */}
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          // <pathname>?sort=asc
          router.push(pathname + '?' + createQueryString('sort', 'asc'))
        }}
      >
        ASC
      </button>
 
      {/* using <Link> */}
      <Link
        href={
          // <pathname>?sort=desc
          pathname + '?' + createQueryString('sort', 'desc')
        }
      >
        DESC
      </Link>
    </>
  )
}
```